# angular.js: equivalent of domReady

Tags: angularjs, domready

Warning: Angular newbie ahead.

I have this code in an angular.js page

```
  <div class="clearfix" ng-controller="Controller">

    <h1>Active Ideas 
    <button type="button" ng-click="search()">get Ideas</button></h1>
    <hr>
```

and then I have defined my controller as:

```
function Controller($scope, $http) {
  $scope.search = function(){...
```

And it works fine.

I'd like to execute search() function when the dom is ready...

I tried calling it from a $(function() {... but I don't know how to manually execute a method from my controller

Also tried with

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
```

But couldn't make it work (and couldn't find much documentation either...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should execute `search` when your Controller is initialized. i.e.

```
function Controller($scope, $http) {
  $scope.search = function(){...};
  $scope.search();
}
```

When Angular's Dependency Injection constructs your controller then you know that the your view is compiled, linked, and ready for initialization code.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to wait for the first digest, otherwise your DOM will be ready but it won't have any value that you have set in your $scope, let's say an element with a ng-repeat linked to an array in your $scope won't be ready. For it to work properly you'll need to wrap your code in a `$timeout(..., 0)`, this way your code will be executed immediately after the first digest.