# Angular.js template doesn't get document css

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, angularjs

I have two templates that populate ng-view, but they don't inherit the document css. Is there a way to get the css to work? I am using this in a jquery mobile page and want the repeat list to have jquery mobile ui.

Comment: this is really annoying!!! i am also facing same problem

Answer (score 1):

`ng-view` simply attaches the HTML to the current DOM; CSS applied to the page will affect it correctly. More likely, jQuery Mobile UI does some JavaScript magic that's not happening when the HTML is added.

For instance, a glance through [the documentation on Listviews](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-methods.html) brings up the following method:

> #### `refresh` - update the listview
>
> If you manipulate a listview via JavaScript (e.g. add new LI elements), you must call the refresh method on it to update the visual styling.
>
> ```
> $('.selector').listview('refresh');
> ```

There's also a section at the bottom of ["List basics & API"](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html):

> #### Updating lists
>
> If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the refresh() method on it to update the styles and create any nested lists that are added. For example:
>
> ```
> $('#mylist').listview('refresh');
> ```
>
> Note that the `refresh()` method only affects **new nodes** appended to a list. This is done for performance reasons. Any list items already enhanced will be ignored by the refresh process. This means that if you change the contents or attributes on an already enhanced list item, these won't be reflected. If you want a list item to be updated, replace it with fresh markup before calling refresh.

Comment: That is helpful, but I don't see how or where to apply that using an Angular directive. When would I call that?

Comment: Well in this case, you'd need to refresh the widget any time the data driving the UI inside the `ng-view` changes--so you'd have to set up a `$watch` manually. Thankfully, someone's already gone through the trouble of integrating Angular with jQuery Mobile: https://github.com/tigbro/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter

Answer (score 0):

ng-view has a [$viewContentLoaded](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngView#$viewContentLoaded) event that is emitted when the ng-view content is reloaded.  Try having a controller or directive scope (or even rootScope) listen for that event and reapply/refresh as @Brandon mentions.

See also [Jquery calls not working in $viewContentLoaded of Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021152/jquery-calls-not-working-in-viewcontentloaded-of-angular) and 
[angular.js: equivalent of domReady](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558220/angular-js-equivalent-of-domready) - maybe you can just call the reapply/refresh stuff at the bottom of each main controller in your view (no need for $viewContentLoaded here).